# Kivy- Is it possible to add superscript or subscript text to button

Tags: python, kivy

As the title suggest, apart from the text in the center on the button I want to put text in any of the corners of the button. One possible way to do so is to use a background image. But I want to know, can it really be done?

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string("""
<ButtonGridLayout>:
    rows: 2
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10
    Button:
        text: 'Hello'
    Button:
        text: 'Hellow'
""")
class ButtonGridLayout(GridLayout):
    pass
class ButtonApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ButtonGridLayout()
if __name__=='__main__':
    ButtonApp().run()
```

Right there inside the blue circle in this image
[ButtonApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38lBk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add Labels inside your button:

here i create a helper rule to avoid repeating stuff about how i want to size some labels

```
<AutoSizedLabel@Label>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: self.texture_size
    padding: 10
```

then, i add a floatlayout inside my button, to the size/position of the button, to make positionning of these labels easier, i also create dynamic properties to be able to easily pass text values for these labels, and i nest them in the FloatLayout, using the pos_hint system to position them.

```
<MyCrazyButton@Button>:
    top_right_text: ''
    top_left_text: ''
    bottom_right_text: ''
    bottom_left_text: ''

    FloatLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos

        AutoSizedLabel:
            text: root.top_right_text or ''
            pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'right': 1}

        AutoSizedLabel:
            text: root.bottom_right_text or ''
            pos_hint: {'y': 0, 'right': 1}

        AutoSizedLabel:
            text: root.top_left_text or ''
            pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'x': 0}

        AutoSizedLabel:
            text: root.bottom_left_text or ''
            pos_hint: {'y': 0, 'x': 0}
```

and then i can use it like this:

```
MyCrazyButton:
    text: 'boring text'
    bottom_left_text: 'bl'
    top_left_text: 'tl'
    bottom_right_text: 'br'
    top_right_text: 'tr'
```

edit: of course, i did all the possibilities, if you don't need all of them, you can avoid creating a lot of unnecessary widgets by removing them from the rule!

Comment: padding for autosizedlabel was not working, removed it and it looks fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Unicode to get superscripts and subscripts. For example your text in second button can be `text: 'Hellow\u2074'`,  which is `Hellow` with a superscript 4. Check out [unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/unicode.html) and [superscripts-and-subscripts](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/superscripts-and-subscripts/)

Comment: that is correct if the font supports superscript and subscript

Comment: this is not what i asked

Comment: @titusarmah99: "It it possible to add superscipt or subscript text to button"